# 'layout_bellow' attribute not declared

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-xml

This is an Android project in VS 2015 Community with Xamarin.
In XML, I have the standard linear layout and inside it a relative layout with two buttons.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
      <Button
          android:text="Button 2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/button2"
          android:layout_bellow="@id/button1"
          />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

1: The editor has a green underline bellow 'android:layout_bellow'. When I hover over it, I see "The 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_bellow' attribute is not declared.
2. I am trying to use the relative layout to position the buttons in the center of the screen.
How can I fix (1), and how can I do (2) ?

Comment: Why is your RelativeLayout nested inside a LinearLayout?! Nesting layouts is bad for performances.

Comment: That is how I (a novice on layouts) understand it. Please suggest an other solution. How can I put the buttons in one line, and centered on the screen ?

Comment: Remove the LinearLayout, since it's unnecessary. Place the center button, the the other two ones. One to the left of it and the other one to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Change your spelling to `android:layout_below` instead of `android:layout_bellow`.or use the below code

```
          <Button
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_above="@id/button2" />
          <Button
              android:text="Button 2"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/button2"

              />
```

Comment: I was typing the answer... Ugh! I'm always a second late. Please flag this question as off topic due to the problem being a typo

Comment: You are right about the spelling - thanks. However the problem still persists. The 'android:layout_below' string is still underlined and I see the warning/info when I hover over it.

Comment: Clean your project

Comment: It is as if the XML parser/compiler is not up to date. Why does it understand one keyword and not an other ? Is there a way of updating it ?

Answer (score 0):

@Nick.P The original problem was that the attribute was not declared. Your solution does not fix it, it's a work around. -1

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for contributing towards this question. Eventually, using the design view I removed everything including the linear layout, and added a relative layout instead, with my two buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <Button
        p1:text="Button 1"
        p1:layout_centerVertical="true"
        p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button 2"
        p1:layout_centerVertical="true"
        p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        p1:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now all the underlining has gone, and I was able to create my two side-by-side buttons centered (sort of) on the screen. my purpose was to investigate how to go about things, and now I have an insight.